# Write PHP code to ensure that the following user submitted data are in correct format roll_Number,name,email and phone_Number

Tags: php, database

Write PHP code to ensure that the following user submitted data are in correct format

```
roll_Number,name,email and phone_Number

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $roll_Number=$_POST['uroll'];
    $name=$_POST['uname'];
    $email=$_POST['uemail'];
    $phone_Number=$_POST['uphone'];
    echo $roll_Number;

    if(filter_var($roll_Number,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)  && filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && filter_var($phone_Number,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
        echo "Valid data!!!";
        //establish a connection
        $db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

        //create database
        $sql="CREAte database db_validate__2014";

        //create table
        $sql.="create table studentInfo
                (
                    roll_Number INT primary key,
                    name VARCHAR(45) not null,
                    email varchar(45) null,
                    phone int not null
                )";

        //insert data into table

        $sql.="insert into studentInfo
            values('$roll_Number','$name','$email','$phone_Number')";
        $sqlres=mysqli_multi_query($db,$sql);

        if($sqlres){
            echo "Operation successful!!!";
        }else{
            echo "Operation failed!!!";
        }

        //close the connection
        mysqli_close($db);



    }else{
        echo "Invalid data enter again!!!";
    }
}else{
    echo "<form action='' method='post' >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    roll_Number:<input type='number' name='uroll' > 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    name:<input type='text' name='uname' >  
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    Email:<input type='text' name='uemail' >    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    phone_Number:<input type='number' name='uphone' >   
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='Submit' name='Submit' >    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: what is the problem, what error you are getting  ?

Comment: even if i give a correct input types it showing me invalid input type..

Comment: Why don't you check/echo/print out what the data types are? You should then be able to troubleshoot your `filter_var` funcitons

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to place this   $db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

```
        //create database
        $sql="CREAte database db_validate__2014";

        //create table
        $sql.="create table studentInfo
                (
                    roll_Number INT primary key,
                    name VARCHAR(45) not null,
                    email varchar(45) null,
                    phone int not null
                )";
```

above this if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ line

Comment: i have to validate user inputs if they are correct or not.even if the data is valid it giving me invalid input type.what should I do?